# How to find multiple occurrences of integers in a linked list

Tags: linked-list, integer, find-occurrences

I'm having trouble figuring out an algorithm that will help me find multiple occurrences of integers in a linked list

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
list<int> mylist;

mylist.push_back(1);
mylist.push_back(4);
mylist.push_back(1);
mylist.push_back(3);
mylist.push_back(4);
mylist.push_back(5);

list<int>::iterator iter;
for( iter = mylist.begin(); iter != mylist.end(); iter++)
{
    cout << *iter << endl;
}



for(list<int>::iterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); it++)
{

    list<int>::iterator finder = std::find(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), *it);
    while   (finder != mylist.end())
    {

        finder = std::find(++finder, mylist.end(), *it);
        if(finder != mylist.end())
        {

            cout << "catch it" << endl;
            cout << * finder;
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```